# SQL to select rows with the 2 most recent dates

Tags: sql

I'm currently struggling with a dataset in which snapshots are saved for multiple companies. That snapshot is performed once a week but is divided over 2 days. I already got the dataset to work with just one recent day with:

```
Where [TRANSDATE] = (SELECT MAX(TRANSDATE) FROM QBE_INVENTDIMPHYSLOGGING)
```

But how do I include the 2 most recent dates (always a Saturday and Sunday). So in case of August, that would be 20th of August and the 21st, but I can't use those dates as hard values because it will change every week and I only want to import the most recent weekend. Could anyone assist how to tackle this? Many thanks in advance!

Gr. Diana

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please tag your question with the actual database you are using, i.e. SQL Server, PostgreSQL, MySQL, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On SQL Server, you may use `TOP`:

```sql
SELECT TOP 2 *
FROM QBE_INVENTDIMPHYSLOGGING
ORDER BY TRANSDATE DESC;
```

If you had to stick with your current subquery approach (which, by the way, is completely fine for finding rank 1 records), you could extend using:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM QBE_INVENTDIMPHYSLOGGING
WHERE TRANSDATE = (SELECT MAX(TRANSDATE) FROM QBE_INVENTDIMPHYSLOGGING) OR
      TRANSDATE = (SELECT MAX(TRANSDATE)
                   FROM QBE_INVENTDIMPHYSLOGGING
                   WHERE TRANSDATE < (SELECT MAX(TRANSDATE)
                                      FROM QBE_INVENTDIMPHYSLOGGING));
```

If you want to capture all ties, then use `TOP 2 WITH TIES` instead of the first option.  You may also use the `RANK()` analytic function.

Comment: Great, thank you, I already tried using the top 2 but I got an error and I now see that's because I didn't order the transdate

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
Where [TRANSDATE] IN (SELECT top 2 TRANSDATE FROM QBE_INVENTDIMPHYSLOGGING order by TRANSDATE desc)
```